# Find next due date in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds Scheduled Transactions. A scheduled transaction row contain s a 'first_payment_date', and a 'frequency_id', which can be weekly, every 2 weeks, monthly, yearly (and a few others)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[scheduled_transaction](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [account_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [payment_frequency_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [first_payment_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [last_payment_date] [date] NULL,
    [payment_amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

So, the first date, is the first date the payment should have been made. The last date is the last scheduled date. If null, then there is no end date.

frequency is, 1=once off, 2=weekly, 3=every two weeks, 4=monthly

What I need to do, is list all scheduled transactions, and include the next scheduled payment date. So, based on the first date - I need to work out the next due date - based on todays date.

Is this possible, in a query, or do I need cursors?

Comment: Check out using the datediff and dateadd functions, along with a "tally" aka numbers table. You can use a case statement and datediff to get the # of payments, then join to the tally table to duplicate that many rows, and use dateadd to add the correct units to the first pay date. I can post more info once I get back to my computer in a few hrs if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that work. Functions can be expensive, but I do not select from tables, so it should be fine. Plain and simple calculations.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetNextPayDate(@paymentFreq int, @firstDate datetime, @lastDate datetime, @CurDate datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @Result DATETIME

  SET @Result = @firstDate
  WHILE @firstDate < IsNull(@lastdate, @CurDate + 32)
    BEGIN
    SET @firstDate = CASE @paymentFreq
                    WHEN 1 THEN @firstDate
                    WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @firstDate)
                    WHEN 3 THEN DATEADD(WEEK, 2, @firstDate)
                    WHEN 4 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @firstDate)
                    --YOU CAN ADD YOUR OTHERS IN HERE THAT YOU NEED
                    END
    if @Result > @CurDate or @Result = @firstDate
      RETURN @Result
    ELSE
      SET @Result = @firstDate
    END
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Execute it as

```
Select *, dbo.fn_GetNextPayDate([payment_frequency_type_id], [first_payment_date], [last_payment_date], GetDate()) from [scheduled_transaction]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need the +32. I probably had an idea why, but to be honest, I think you can leave it all together.

Comment: Scalar functions can cause big performance issues if used in any queries, even when the fn does not select from any tables.  I would avoid using scalar functions whenever possible.